Qt::QcheckBox not accessing checkStateChanged(Qt::CheckState) signal
I cannot get Qt 6.2.4 to connect a signal with a slot.
attempting to run:
    ///////////////
    
    Plotrect_Actions::Plotrect_Actions(const QVector<PlotDataRect> &plotdatasets, QWidget *parent):plotdatasets(plotdatasets)
{
    setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    plot=new QCustomPlot(this);
    assert(plot);
    assert(rectplot_box);
    plot->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding,QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
    rectplot_box->addWidget(static_cast<QWidget *>(plot));

    logx->blockSignals(true);
    logx->setText("logscale X");
    connect(logx,SIGNAL(checkStateChanged(Qt::CheckState)),this,SLOT(linearlogXtoggle(Qt::CheckState)));
    logx->blockSignals(false);
    plot->setMouseTracking(true);
    }
    
        ////
//*******************************************************************************
void Plotrect_Actions::linearlogXtoggle(Qt::CheckState checked)        // toggle linlogX_button
{
    if(checked)
    {
        logx->setText("log X");
        linearX=false;
        plot->xAxis->setScaleType(QCPAxis::stLogarithmic);
        plot->rescaleAxes();
        plot->replot();
    }
    else
    {
        logx->setText("linear X");
        linearX=true;
        plot->xAxis->setScaleType(QCPAxis::stLinear);
        plot->rescaleAxes();
        plot->replot();
    }
}

//***************************************************************************************

yields the error:
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such signal QCheckBox::checkStateChanged(Qt::CheckState)

This has me stumped because apparently QCheckBox does have the signal QCheckBox::checkStateChanged (from the documentation).
Any ideas welcome and thanks in advance.

How was linearlogXtoggle declared? Please provide a proper [mre].

The documentation mentions the checkStateChanged signal was created in version 6.7.
The corresponding signal in the previous versions is stateChanged and it will be deprecated in v6.9.

Hi, My bad, Yes, I think you are correct. When I used stateChanged, this worked. Looks like I'm going to need to update my Qt version. Thanks!
